# Exception in GWT Dev Mode + Spring 3.1 + Hibernate 4.0.1

Tags: spring, gwt, jpa-2.0, spring-3, hibernate-4.x

I have a GWT+Hibernate+JPA+Spring configuration file which is OK with Spring 3.0.x + Hibernate 3.6.x. When I upgraded to Spring 3.1 and Hibernate 4.0, the following exception is thrown:

Is there any known incompatibility withe Hibernate 4 and Spring 3.1?

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [META-INF/application-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: myPu] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1455)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:567)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:384)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:283)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:543)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:136)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1220)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:513)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:448)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JettyLauncher$WebAppContextWithReload.doStart(JettyLauncher.java:468)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.RequestLogHandler.doStart(RequestLogHandler.java:115)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:222)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JettyLauncher.start(JettyLauncher.java:672)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.doStartUpServer(DevMode.java:509)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.startUp(DevModeBase.java:1068)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.run(DevModeBase.java:811)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.main(DevMode.java:311)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: naftPu] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:914)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:889)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:73)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:257)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:310)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.spi.ConnectionProvider]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:187)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:150)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:131)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcServicesImpl.java:234)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:159)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:131)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:71)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettingsInternal(Configuration.java:2270)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2266)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1735)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:84)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:904)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not instantiate connection provider [org.hibernate.ejb.connection.InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider]
    at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.ConnectionProviderInitiator.instantiateExplicitConnectionProvider(ConnectionProviderInitiator.java:190)
    at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.ConnectionProviderInitiator.initiateService(ConnectionProviderInitiator.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.ConnectionProviderInitiator.initiateService(ConnectionProviderInitiator.java:54)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:69)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:177)
    ... 49 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.ejb.connection.InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider cannot be cast to org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.spi.ConnectionProvider
    at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.ConnectionProviderInitiator.instantiateExplicitConnectionProvider(ConnectionProviderInitiator.java:187)
    ... 53 more
```

Here is part of my application-context.xml config:

```
<bean id="mainDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" />
    <property name="url" value="***manually deleted***" />
    <property name="username" value="myschema" />
    <property name="password" value="myschema" />
    <property name="initialSize" value="1" />
    <property name="maxActive" value="4" />
    <property name="maxIdle" value="-1" />
    <property name="maxWait" value="10000" />
</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" p:persistenceUnitName="myPu">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="mainDataSource" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" p:showSql="true" p:generateDdl="true"
            p:database="ORACLE" p:databasePlatform="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect" />
    </property>
    <property name="jpaPropertyMap">
        <map merge="true">
            <entry key="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class" />
            <entry key="hibernate.format_sql" value="false" />
            <entry key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="false" />
            <entry key="hibernate.default_schema" value="myschema" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

persistence.xml:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd" version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="myPu" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: Paste mainDataSource bean config and persistence.xml. What's your server? Do you use EJB at all? This class is strange : org.hibernate.ejb.connection.InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider. 

What I found: 
http://relation.to/Bloggers/SomeTipsOnUsingHibernateInJBossAS700Final

Comment: It looks like this: org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence is wrong provider.

Comment: @peter-gwiazda Thanks, that page doesn't help, as I'm outside of JBoss. BTW, there is no other JPA provider for Hibernate other than org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.

Comment: Are you using maven with gwt and jetty plugins?

Comment: My libraries are taken from a Maven repository, but this is not a maven project, nor do I use any jetty plugin. All is done inside Eclipse with its GWT plugin.

Comment: I have the same problem and it only occurs when I run in GWT Dev mode. It works fine when I run it in production mode in my own jetty. I think there is something wrong with the classpath but I don't know what it is.

Comment: Notice that starting of spring 3.1.1 the persistence.xml can be omitted: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.0.RC1/spring-framework-reference/html/new-in-3.1.html#d0e1489

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This issue is fixed [in Hibernate 4.1.4](https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-7084).

---

I had the same problem, and it seems to be related to the Jetty classloader (the GWT plugin uses Jetty for hosted mode), the GWT plugin and Hibernate (although it apparently crops up with other libraries as well).

It's similar to the bug mentioned here [Hibernate Bug Report](https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-7084) but in our cases we're running it via the GWT plugin and it causes a ClassCastException for the ConnectionProvider.

The fix mentioned in the bug report should fix that particular problem.

For org.hibernate.service.classloading.internalClassLoaderServiceImpl set the parent to null via the constructor:

```
this.classClassLoader = new ClassLoader(null) {
        @Override
        protected Class<?> findClass(String name) throws ClassNotFoundException {
            for ( ClassLoader loader : classLoadingClassLoaders ) {
                try {
                    return loader.loadClass( name );
                }
                catch (Exception ignore) {
                }
            }
            throw new ClassNotFoundException( "Could not load requested class : " + name );
        }
};
```

Comment: This is fixed in hibernate 4.1.4

Answer (score 1):

remove ejb3-persistence.jar in the /lib directory if already there; it conflicts with hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar in hibernate 4. That worked for me after having this issue, I achieved to host a GWT, Hibernate 4, Spring 3.1.1 app on Openshift environment https://openshift.redhat.com/app/

Answer (score -2):

I think you don't need to set `<provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>` in `persistence.xml`. Check [the docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html#orm-jpa-setup-lcemfb).

Comment: No change. This element helps JPA decide which provider to choose when there are multiple providers in the classpath.