# ClassCastException InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider Spring 3.1.0, Hibernate 4, JPA EntityManagerFactory

Tags: java, hibernate, spring

Using:

- Spring 3.1.0
- Hibernate 4
- JPA 2
- GWT 2.3.0.

[Similar to [Exception in GWT Dev Mode + Spring 3.1 + Hibernate 4.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8891467/exception-in-spring-3-1-hibernate-4-0-1) ]

When running a very simple GWT application (using the Greeting Service) and adding a spring configuration to the application (via web.xml and related spring configuration files), an exception occurs when the system is brought up in gwt dev mode (from within Eclipse and from the command-line (mvn gwt:run)).

The exception is shown below:

> [WARN] Nested in org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jgkgwtclasscastissueEntityManagerFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/classes/spring-main-config.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: jgkgwtclasscastissue-PU] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.ejb.connection.InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider cannot be cast to org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.spi.ConnectionProvider

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <!-- POM file generated with GWT webAppCreator -->
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.gs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jgkgwtclasscastissue</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>GWT Maven Archetype</name>

    <properties>
        <gwtVersion>2.3.0</gwtVersion>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.6</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.6</maven.compiler.target>
        <webappDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}    </webappDirectory>
        <antlr.version>2.7.6</antlr.version>
        <aopalliance.version>1.0</aopalliance.version>
        <c3p0.version>0.9.1.2</c3p0.version>
        <cglib.version>2.2.2</cglib.version>
        <commons-beanutils.version>1.8.3</commons-beanutils.version>
        <commons-collections.version>3.1</commons-collections.version>
        <commons-logging.version>1.1.1</commons-logging.version>
        <ojdbc6.version>11.1.0.7.0</ojdbc6.version>
        <commons-dbcp.version>1.4</commons-dbcp.version>
        <dom4j.version>1.6.1</dom4j.version>
        <ehcache.version>2.4.6</ehcache.version>
        <javassist.version>3.9.0.GA</javassist.version>
        <javax.inject.version>1.0-PFD-1</javax.inject.version>
        <javax.transaction.version>1.1</javax.transaction.version>
        <junit.version>4.9</junit.version>
        <log4j.version>1.2.16</log4j.version>
        <slf4j-api.version>1.6.1</slf4j-api.version>
        <slf4j-log4j12.version>1.6.1</slf4j-log4j12.version>

        <org.aspectj.version>1.6.10</org.aspectj.version>
        <org.hibernate.version>4.0.0.Final</org.hibernate.version>
        <org.hibernate-commons-annotations.version>4.0.1.Final</org.hibernate-commons-annotations.version>
            <org.hibernate.hibernate-validator.version>4.1.0.Final</org.hibernate.hibernate-validator.version>
        <org.hibernate.jpamodelgen.version>1.1.1.Final</org.hibernate.jpamodelgen.version>
        <org.springframework.version>3.1.0.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
        <org.springframework.data.version>1.0.1.RELEASE</org.springframework.data.version>
        <wagon-ssh.version>1.0-beta-6</wagon-ssh.version>

    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j-api.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j-log4j12.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.7</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>${org.hibernate-commons-annotations.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${org.hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${org.hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
            <version>${org.hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-asm</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>    
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>aopalliance</groupId>
            <artifactId>aopalliance</artifactId>
            <version>${aopalliance.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>${org.aspectj.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-instrument</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-instrument-tomcat</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.data.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-commons-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
            <version>${ojdbc6.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
            <version>${commons-beanutils.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
            <version>${org.hibernate.jpamodelgen.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>${commons-dbcp.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <!-- Generate compiled stuff in the folder used for developing mode -->
        <outputDirectory>${webappDirectory}/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>

        <plugins>

            <!-- GWT Maven Plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>test</goal>
                            <goal>i18n</goal>
                            <goal>generateAsync</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <runTarget>jgkgwtclasscastissue.html</runTarget>
                    <hostedWebapp>${webappDirectory}</hostedWebapp>
                                <i18nMessagesBundle>com.gs.client.Messages</i18nMessagesBundle>
                    </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Copy static web files before executing gwt:run -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exploded</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <webappDirectory>${webappDirectory}</webappDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

It is unclear where the problem is.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Show us your spring configuration files.

Comment: The short solution is to use an external server (Tomcat) under eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

I remember having the same issue sometimes back, in my lib/ I had ejb3-persistence.jar which was conflicting with hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar introduced by upgrading to hibernate 4 and Spring 3.1.1, I got rid of the ejb3-persistence.jar and `javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: jgkgwtclasscastissue-PU] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory: java.lang.ClassCastException` was sorted.

*Try earliest versions of Hibernate (3.3) and Spring (3.0.7). Very often it's impossible to use latest versions together - magical exceptions occurs.*

Answer (score 0):

Same problem found here : [Exception in GWT Dev Mode + Spring 3.1 + Hibernate 4.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8891467/exception-in-gwt-dev-mode-spring-3-1-hibernate-4-0-1)

It comes from a classloader problem on Hibernate which seems incompatible with GWT/jetty shell mode. The bug is still opened on Hibernate but you can apply a patch (see https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-7084)

Answer (score -1):

Try earliest versions of Hibernate (3.3) and Spring (3.0.7). Very often it's impossible to use latest versions together - magical exceptions occurs.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Alex.  Unfortunately, there are some features we need in the later versions of Hibernate (4) and Spring (3.1.0)